# Es posible programar un apagado de un equipo linux si no han ingresado al server en X dias?

Tags: linux, crontab

--
Hola comunidad, mi consulta es si es posible que se pueda configurar linux si en X tiempo o X dias no se haya hecho ninguna sesion al equipo, ejemplo: una maquina virtual que no haya recibido logueos desde hace 20 dias.

Saudos,

Comment: Es posible, pero puede ser bastante complejo si quires una solución 100% genérica. Es más fácil hacerlo para casos específicos, por ejemplo, si es un usuario el que inicia sesión, o son pocos y en un ambiente controlado.

Comment: Claro, comprendo el tema lo menciono para el control de recursos de maquinas virtuales, en este caso pues para ahorrar recursos voy a tener N virtuales pero algunas no se usan tanto y no es necesario que siempre esten arriba.

Comment: pues, debieras mencionar las condiciones específicas sobre las que corren, para que sea manejable escribir una respuesta en el formato de SO. Encontrás más información en [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crear un pequeño script bash para validar y realizar dicha tarea.

Mi propuesta es la siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Obtener la fecha de hace 20 días atrás
mi_fecha=$(date -d "$date -20 days" +"%Y-%m-%d")

#Buscar que existan inicios en el sistema de 20 días atrás en adelante
numero_logins_encontrados=$(last -s $mi_fecha -n1 | head -n 1 | wc -l)

#Validar los inicios de sesion en los ultimos 20 días
if [ $numero_logins_encontrados -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Sin inicios de session en los últimos 20 días, apagando sistema..."
        shutdown -h now
else
        echo "Se ha detectado inicios de sesion en los ultimos 20 dias"
fi
```

Comando last

- Despliega informacion sobre los inicios de sesion en el sistema.
- Parametro -s "since" para recuperar registros a partir de una fecha
  en especifico.
- Parametro -n numero de lineas a mostrar.

Ya con el comando "crontab -e", llamas a este script y defines la frecuencia para estar validando si se cumplen las condiciones para el apagado. Un pequeño ejemplo:

```
#Environment Variables
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

#Correr diariamente a las 12:00AM
0 0 * * * /usr/local/sbin/validar_logins_hechos_en_los_ultimos_20_dias.sh
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias validare las situaciones que me comentas, creo que pueden funcionarmete bastante bien.